# pig latin change tuple value based on condition during generate

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to change the value of a tuple when generating - based on some condtion.

that is if the value is 'x' then set it to 'y' in the output tuple.

my dataset

```
(name,code,id)

(real,mt,27426)
(real,st,3227325)
(fake,st_500,695248)
(fake,st_400,1110868629)
(fake,st_500,1160891426)
(fake,st_500,1320802309)
(fake,st_500,1370836855)
(fake,st_500,1420855918)
(fake,st_500,1600833465)
(real,mt,1640827448)
(fake,st_400,1650848520)
(fake,st_500,1750817885)
(fake,st_500,1820826847)
(fake,st_500,1860897308)
(real,mt,1870855243)
```

I would like to do the following

```
A = FOREACH dataset GENERATE name, (code=='st_500') ? 'mt' : (code=='st_400') ? 'st' : code, id;
```

Is there an easy way to change the value of the tuples when generating?

**EDIT**

I could probably use REPLACE but how would I do multiple replaces.

e.g.

```
REPLACE(code, 'st_500', 'mt') or REPLACE(code, 'st_400', 'st')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Pig 0.12 you can use [case](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#arithmetic):

```
A = FOREACH dataset  GENERATE name, (
  CASE code
    WHEN 'st_500' THEN 'mt'
    WHEN 'st_400' THEN 'st'
    ELSE code
  END
) as code ,id;
```

Comment: how stupid is SO, edits must be at least 6 characters???? what if i had to just add 'as'

Comment: You could just ask the original poster to make the change for you. They are not limited by character limitations.